# module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I get the following error with the code `import keras:`

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list'
```

Comment: `import keras` works fine with `Tensorflow==2.7` and `Keras=2.7`. Use keras>=2.3. Thanks!

Comment: Found any fix? I too get the same error with `import tensorflow`